# Implementing Favourites Section Of Table View Using UserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, xcode9

I'm currently developing an application for IOS that has 2 tabs. A home view, which consists of a table of images with actions when you click on them, and a favourites view which allows users to view their favourite images and actions. I'm currently trying to figure out a way to save this favourites data once the application has been closed. It seems to simple for core data, yet I can't seem to get my head around UserDefaults.

I have a favourite button inside of a view that appears when the user clicks the favourite button, it adds the image title to a list and reloads the table using that list inside of the favourites tab. This is working fine with a normal array variable. When I try implementing  UserDefaults, it doesn't seem to reload the table when I click on the favourites tab, however when I close the app and restart it using multitasking (swipe up) and restart the app the table forms and all the data is remembered and set up. Is there any way for the data to be remembered and stored in the UserDefaults variable when the app closes and when the app restarts use that variable, and while the app is running use the normal variable to reload the table from?

Here's my favourites tab code for the table:

```
import UIKit
var favRow = 0
class FavouritesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    let favouritesavedimages = userDefaults.object(forKey: "Data") as? [String] ?? [String]()
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        tableView.reloadData()
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return favouritesavedimages.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "imageCell2") as? FavouritesImageCellTableViewCell {
            cell.configureCellFavourites(image: UIImage(named: favouritesavedimages[indexPath.row])!)
            return cell
        } else {
            return FavouritesImageCellTableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        favRow = indexPath.row
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let favouritesavedimages = userDefaults.object(forKey: "Data") as? [String] ?? [String]()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

}

Here's my code for the page with the favourite button:

```
    import UIKit
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var favouriteImages: [String] = []
    var isFavourite =             [false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,f    alse,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false]
    class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
 let favourites = userDefaults.object(forKey: "FavData") as? [Bool] ?? [Bool]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if !isFavourite[row]
    {
        favouriteButton.image = UIImage(named: "favourite")
    } else {
        favouriteButton.image = UIImage(named: "defavourite")
    }
    secondImageView.image = secondImages[row]
    secondTitle.text = tutorialTitles[row]
    secondTutorialText.text = tutorialText[row]
}
@IBAction func favouriteButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if !isFavourite[row] {
        setOnFavourite()
    } else {
        setOnDeFavourite()
    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var favouriteButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTutorialText: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondImageView: UIImageView!


func setOnFavourite()
{
    isFavourite[row] = true
    favouriteButton.image = UIImage(named: "defavourite")
    favouriteImages.append(String(row + 1))
    userDefaults.set(favouriteImages, forKey: "Data")
    userDefaults.set(isFavourite, forKey: "FavData")
}
func setOnDeFavourite()
{
    isFavourite[row] = false
    favouriteButton.image = UIImage(named: "favourite")
    favouriteImages = favouriteImages.filter{$0 != String(row)}
    userDefaults.set(favouriteImages, forKey: "Data")
    userDefaults.set(isFavourite, forKey: "FavData")
}
```

}

Thanks, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Problem description is fine. But we need to see your code first. Edit question with what you’ve tried.

Comment: OK Done! Hope this helps